# Rubik's Slide Proof's and Symmetries in a Rubik's Slide

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups

$\quad$In the February edition of The Mathematical Association of America Monthly there is a article called "$\mathit{Rubik's\ on\ the\ Torus}$". Where they are dealing with solving problems involving the electronic puzzle game called the Rubik's Slide.

$\mathbf{\underline{NOTE:}}$ I've given all the details about this topic that I believe will help give you an idea of what I'm working with. I've also tried to make this as clean as possible, but If you believe I should somehow break this up into a smaller question or multiple questions tell me and I will do it.

**Important: Permutation Multiplication Goes From Left to Right in This Article!**

$\mathbf{\underline{Introduction:}}$ So we have: $$\text {Vertical Shift} = (147)(258)(369)$$$$\text{Horizontal Shift} = (123)(456)(789)$$$$\text {Clockwise rotation around center}=(12369874)$$Where my $3\times3$ Rubik's Slide looks like this:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 2 & 3\\
        4 & 5 & 6\\
        7 & 8 & 9
        \end{bmatrix}$$
$\mathbf{\underline{Lemma 1:}}$ The subgroup $<h,v>$ generated by $h$ and $v$ is abelian and of order $S_9$.

$\underline{Proof:}$ By computation we can see that
$$hv=(159)(267)(348)=vh.$$

We also know that $$h^3=\varepsilon=v^3$$

I believe now I can make the assumption that $$\text{"If a subgroup is generated by two cyclic groups is commutative that the subgroups is also abelian."}$$ I think it's a theorem, I just can't find it.

Thus $$<h,v>=\{h^iv^j:i,j=0,1,2\}=S_9$$
$\mathbf{\underline{Lemma 2:}}$ $$c^3h=(14)(2739568) \  \text{and} \ (c^3h)^7=(14)$$

$\underline{Proof:}$ By Computation.

The one that I really stuck on is this one,

$\mathbf{\underline{Theorem 3:}}$ The group $<h,v,c>$ contains every transposition in $S_9$; hence $<h,v,c>=S_9$

The proof that is given in the article states that to transpose two squares, $x$ and $y$

1) Repeatedly apply $h$ and $v$ to move $x$ to position $5$ and to call this series of moves $\sigma$

2) Repeatedly apply $c$ to move $y$ to position $2$ and call this series of moves $\tau$

3) Now apply $h^{-1}$ to move $x$ to position $4$ and $y$ to position $1$.

4) Now swap $x$ and $y$ using Lemma 2.

5) Lastly apply $h\tau^{-1}\sigma^{-1}$

6) Thus the resulting product of moves, $\sigma\tau h^{-1}(c^3h)^7h\tau^{-1}\sigma^{-1}=\ \text{transposition} \ (x,y)$

$\mathbf{\underline{What\ I\ Need\ Help\ With:}}$

I completely believe it works and have proven multiple cases. The problem I'm having is how to prove that it works for all choices of $x$ and $y$.

$\quad$So far I have been looking into conjugacy classes, but I can't seem to find a way to use them to prove this formula.

$\quad$The best Idea I've come up with is to prove that I can transpose any two neighbors with each other without effecting any other square. The reason I'm doing this is because once I prove that I can do that with every neighbor ($12$ cases) I can prove the big transposition equation by saying that any transposition is just the product of transpositions. Therefore since I can transpose every neighbor I can transpose any two squares on the Rubik's slide. So far I've only figured out a couple of the cases.

$\quad$This is where the symmetry comes in. If I can find the vertical and horizontal symmetries of the Rubik's Slide I believe I can narrow down my cases to like $4$ instead of $12$.

Comment: Which of the 6 steps in the proof do you have trouble with?

Comment: I understand the concept behind the proof, but I'm having trouble proving that step $6$ works for any possible combination of squares $x$ and $y$. I'm trying to come up with a mathematically rigorous proof.

Comment: x @Fmonkey: But step 6 just restates and summarizes what you have already done in the first 5 steps. If you agree that steps 1-3 combine to something that moves $x$ to position $4$ and $y$ to position $1$, then conjugating your known combination for $(14)$ with that setup _necessarily_ yields a transposition of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: I guess I'm having trouble writing it in a mathematically rigorous manner. I obviously am over thinking it, but I'm trying to make it rigorous enough to be able to present it to fellow graduate students.

Comment: In a presentation, I think making it more "rigorous" than the formulation you've quoted would amount to disguising the forest with trees. But depending on the audience, you might make a point of this being a _general_ technique for showing that a given set of permutations generate $S_n$: first show that _some_ transposition is made, then show that any two chosen elements can be brought into the right position, and conjugation then does the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have trouble arranging your understanding of the proof, I suggest splitting it into two parts.

**Lemma, for any permutation group.** For any $x,y,a,b$, if $\rho$ is a permutation such that $\rho(x)=a$ and $\rho(y)=b$, then $\rho^{-1}(a\,b)\rho=(x\,y)$ -- or, depending on whether you compose left-to-right or right-to-left, $\rho(a\,b)\rho^{-1}=(x\,y)$.

You can prove the lemma completely algebraically, by verifying that the two permutations it asserts are equal take the same elements to the same results.

**Observation.** For any two different positions $x$ and $y$ on the slide, there is a sequence of moves that take $x$ to position $4$ and $y$ to position $1$.

This is just step 1,2,3 in the proof sketch, steps you say you do trust.

**Corollary.** Any transposition is realizable in the slide group, by the Lemma with $a=4, b=1$ and $\rho$ being the sequence of moves from the observation.